# how can i get the videos from internal storage of moto g4 plus

Tags: android-studio, internal

I want to fetch the videos from moto g4 plus and display them as thumbnails in gridview and onclick of item of the gridview the video should be played. I can't find any way to give the path of internal storage. Please help .

Comment: please show some effort, like what have you tried done so far

Comment: I tried to use the video view .for that i created a raw file placed a video in it and it plays . But basically i can not find a way to give the path for the videos which are located on internal storage in mobile. I want to fetch all videos.

Comment: edit your question and add codes about what you have done so far and what you want to achieve